# How to get the path except file name in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am running test.ps1 file .

Here i want to get the file loaction without the file name and assign that to one variable.

**ex: 
 E:\Userdata\file1\file2\test.ps1
I want only E:\Userdata\file1\file2**

How to get it and what is the command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
(resolve-path $myinvocation.line) |split-path -parent
```

Answer (score 2):

For PowerShell 3.0 I suggest checking out the automatic variable $PSScriptRoot